# Why WPF grid width doesn't change during for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, grid

I'm trying to make a button to slide when I click on it. To do this, I made a grid to change it's column width so the button seems to move around:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhbNq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7VFD.png)

When I click on the grid, the width of the first column is checked. If it's 0, then it's changed to the width of the grid. Same for the other side.

I want to make this to happen in an animation, so the width changed within time, so I did a for loop to modify the width of the columns so the slider move when I click on it.

My code below:

```
private void MouseLeftDown_TwoSideButton(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    double width = TwoSideButton.ActualWidth;
    double desiredColumnWidth = width - (TwoSideButton_Mid1Column.ActualWidth + TwoSideButton_Mid2Column.ActualWidth);

    int steps = 5;
    double stepSize = desiredColumnWidth / steps;

    bool leftSelected = true ? TwoSideButton_LeftSideColumn.ActualWidth == 0 : false;

    // Here I want to see the changes during for loop, not at the end of the loop.
    for (int i = 1; i <= steps; i++)
    {
        if (leftSelected)
        {
            TwoSideButton_LeftSideColumn.Width = new GridLength(i * stepSize);
            TwoSideButton_RightSideColumn.Width = new GridLength(desiredColumnWidth - i * stepSize);
        }
        else if (!leftSelected)
        {
            TwoSideButton_LeftSideColumn.Width = new GridLength(desiredColumnWidth - i * stepSize);
            TwoSideButton_RightSideColumn.Width = new GridLength(i * stepSize);
        }
    }
}
```

And XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="TwoSideButton" Width="200" Height="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftDown_TwoSideButton">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TwoSideButton_LeftSideColumn" Width="0"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TwoSideButton_Mid1Column" Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TwoSideButton_Mid2Column" Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TwoSideButton_RightSideColumn" Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="DarkOrange"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="RoyalBlue"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Gray"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TwoSideButton_LeftText" Text="Trabajando" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TwoSideButton_RightText" Text="Terminado" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Thanks!

Comment: *"I want to see the changes during for loop"* - you are trying to *animate* gridcolumn width? Why not using [animations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3181139/1997232) for this? Otherwise you forgot to add a kind of *delay* (`await Task.Delay(10)`) or loop will occurs too fast. Also worth mentioning that in WPF many things (e.g. layouting, rendering, etc.) occurs via `Dispatcher` queue, often you need to invoke continuation after changing property value.

Comment: The MouseLeftDown_TwoSideButton method - including the loop - run in the UI thread, which is blocked until return from the method. Consider using a DispatcherTimer, or take a look at async/await. A simple solution may be to declare the method `async`, and add something like `await Task.Delay(100)` in the loop body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid cannot refresh itself automatically while your loop is still running

One possible workaround is to make the whole event handler asynchronous by adding an await delay inside your loop:

```
await Task.Delay(100);
```

you will need to mark the your event handler as async for that to compile:

```
private async void MouseLeftDown_TwoSideButton(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```